# Why my Android application stops receiving notifications after a restart on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Android Studio 2.2 Beta 3.
I develop an application on a tablet. This application should receive GCM notifications to do specific tasks.

I boot the tablet and start working linked with USB cable to Android Studio 2.2 beta3. 
The application is working fine and receive notifications as expected.

I spot a bug or I want to add a new feature or change a fragment element in the related xml file (basically I do any small modification).

To deploy the fix, I hit the `Rerun'app (^F5)`, the application starts but receive no notification.

To make it work again, I need to reboot the tablet.

I used the [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main) sample to implement the notifications.

```
        <service
            android:name="fr.xxxxx.yyyyyy.playServices.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="fr.xxxxx.yyyyyy.playServices.RegistrationIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

The registration service.

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Instance creation of RegistrationIntentService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "RegistrationIntentService.onCreate");
    onTokenRefresh();
}

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is also called
 * when the InstanceID token is initially generated, so this is where
 * you retrieve the token.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

The message service (the `Log.i` lines in `onMessageReceived` are not executed when I restart the application)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingSvc";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Message from: " + message.getFrom());
        Log.i(TAG, "Data: " + message.getData().size() + " entries");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : message.getData().entrySet()) {
            Log.i(TAG, entry.getKey() + " --> " + entry.getValue());
        }
        sendNotification(message);
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
        final RemoteMessageDelegate delegate = GlobalModel.getInstance().getCurrentRemoteMessageDelegate();
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.messageReceived(message);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("Message received (%s) but no delegate set: message is lost!", message.getData().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: why is this happening and how can I fix this?

It's a real pain in the a** to reboot the device each time I make a small modification.

Comment: Have you verified that your application server is receiving the updated registration token from the new app instance? And that your server is using it to send messages?

Comment: @gnuf : Yes. Padding to comply min length.